# set SelectionChanged in ListView Clickmode = "pressed" in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a ListView and i want ListView to be selected when Mouse pressed. (Like ClickMode property of Buttons). is there any solution ?

Comment: What have you tried and where encountered problems? Have you tried the *SelectionMode* property of *ListView*?

Comment: @Romasz I want to make ListView to be selected when Mouse pressed and we have this for Buttons with ClickMode property but here we do not have this property in the ListView. I tried to put button in ListView template and change its ClickMode property but i couldn't access object that is clicked in the ListView (i think i should do something like it)! and you said  SelectionMode property ,i think, it's for selection of items single or Multiple and etc  and not for ClickMode!

Comment: If you enable SelectionMode as Multiple, you will be able to select items by clicking mouse/touching items. You will have to describe your question better.

Comment: @Romasz my problem is that i have a touch Lcd , accepts Press mode of click and it doesn't work with click with both pressed and released ! can you describe more how SelectionMode can help me! thanks.

Comment: Seems like I don't understand your question, please edit it and add some more information, code you have tried, where are the problems and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to put button in ListView template and change its ClickMode property

The [`SelectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_Selector_SelectionChanged) is triggered when mouse released which is  by default. It seems like we cannot change it. So we can put button in `ListView` item template and change its click mode as what you thought about, or register a [`PointerPressed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_PointerPressed) event for the container inside item template which will be triggered when mouse pressed not released.

> but i couldn't access object that is clicked in the ListView

To access which item is clicked you still can use property like [SelectedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_Selector_SelectedItem) of `ListView` to get the selected item. For example:

XAML Code

```
 <ListView Name="CategoryLIstView" Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{x:Bind categories}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="CategoryLIstView_SelectionChanged" ItemClick="CategoryLIstView_ItemClick" PointerPressed="CategoryLIstView_PointerPressed">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Category">
             <StackPanel  Margin="0" PointerPressed="StackPanel_PointerPressed">
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                     <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Yu Gothic" FontSize="17"/>
                 </StackPanel>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate> 
 </ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
  private async void StackPanel_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("point press").ShowAsync();
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(CategoryLIstView.SelectedIndex); 
  }
```